# System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox's implementation of TextBoxBase.ClearUndo()

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox, undo

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox_methods%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), the description of the method `ClearUndo` is:

```
"Clears information about the most recent operation from the undo buffer of the text box."
```

Now, contrary to what the documentation says, the override of this method in `System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox` appears to be clearing the entire undo buffer, instead of just the most recent operation. Is this discrepancy between the documentation and the implementation a known issue, or should I suspect that something else it amiss? I have been unable to find any official information on this which is why I am now asking the question here. I have tested it with `.NET Framework 4.0`.

Comment: Reading the .NET 4 source from [here](http://reflector.webtropy.com/default.aspx/4@0/4@0/untmp/DEVDIV_TFS/Dev10/Releases/RTMRel/wpf/src/Framework/System/Windows/Controls/RichTextBox@cs/1305600/RichTextBox@cs) would infer that it doesn't override TextBoxBase's `ClearUndo()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct. ILSpy shows this in `TextBoxBase` (the `RichTextBox` doesn't override it):

```
public void ClearUndo()
{
    if (base.IsHandleCreated)
    {
        base.SendMessage(205, 0, 0);
    }
}
```

The message 205 is `EM_EMPTYUNDOBUFFER`:

```
// Header file
#define EM_EMPTYUNDOBUFFER 0x00CD // 0x00CD = 205

// C#
EM_EMPTYUNDOBUFFER = 205
```

Comment: Thank you! So it is even worse then, I thought that perhaps they had forgotten to update the documentation for `RichTextBox`.

Comment: It would appear their definition of "the most recent" is everything .. if you read further into the documentation what they say is correct. However the initial read makes it very misleading indeed, so I can see your confusion.